# Calculate an integration on a sphere

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

Suppose $A \in R^{n \times n}$ is a symmetry matrix, I want to calculate the following thing:
\begin{equation}
   \int_{\|x\|_2^2 = 1} x^TAx d\sigma(x) 
\end{equation}

i.e. I want to calculate the term $x^TAx$ over the unit sphere in $R^n$. What would I get?

Here $\sigma(x)$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on sphere.

My guess is something related to the eigenvalue of $A$, or maybe something related to $tr(A)$. But I don't know how to do the calculation.

Edit: Thanks for all the replies. Now I know how to deal with the case where I want to evaluate the mean of $x^TAx$. The trick here is to smartly diagonalize it.

However, I'm still confused about how to compute an integration on the sphere. The reason is that the thing I really want to evaluate is something like:
$\int_{S^{n-1}}\frac{1}{x^TAx} d\sigma(x) $, where we can assume $A$ is positive definite. So in this case, we still need to face with the difficulty of tedious sphere coordinate transform. Is there any reference to this kind of integration? If we can not calculate its value, is there any method we can bound this thing?

Comment: What is the measure $\sigma$ in your question ? Is that Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: Yes, it should be the standard Lebesgue measure on the sphere.

Comment: Have you considered writing $A=Q^TDQ$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$? You could set $u=Qx$ and use that fact that hyperspheres centered around the origin are invariant under orthogonal transformations to write this as $$\int_{\|x\|=1}(\lambda_1x_1^2+\dots +\lambda_n x_n^2)\mathrm{d}V_{n-1}$$ With symmetry it's not hard to see that $$\int_{\|x\|=1}x_i^2 \mathrm{d}V_{n-1}=\frac{\text{Vol}_{n-1}(\|x\|=1)}{n}$$

Comment: Actually I can understand the part of matrix decomposition or matrix transform. But what I really not sure is about how to deal with the integration over sphere.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861461/)

Comment: A good trick is to consider $Z\sim N(0,I_n)$ since $Z/\|Z\|$ is uniform on the sphere. Therefore $$\int_{S_{n-1}}f(x)dV_{n-1}(x)=Vol_{n-1}(S_{n-1})\times E(f(Z/\|Z\|)).$$ This can even be used for computing $Vol_{n-1}(S_{n-1}).$

Comment: About  your question $\int_{S_{n-1}}\frac{dV_{n-1}(x)}{\lambda x_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_n x_n^2},$ I can mention $$E\left[\left(\frac{\|Z\|^2}{\lambda Z_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_n Z_n^2}\right)^{n/2}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1\ldots \lambda_n}}$$

Comment: This is something that is really similar to what I want to calculate actually. But How can we derive it? I might want to learn something from it.

Comment: Btw, what is the distribution that you take expectation of?

Comment: $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ are independent and $N(0,1)$. I will give details later.